# Vectorize a function that requires grouping in R

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization

Say I have some data that has multiple data points where some share a group identifier:

```
group <- rep(c(1:5), times=3)
cost <- rnorm(length(group), 100, 5)
current_score <- rnorm(length(group), 7, 2)
future_score <- current_score*runif(1)

dat <- data.frame(group, cost, current_score, future_score)
```

and a function that gives an overall weighted group score:

```
wt_score <- function(group, dat)
{
  one_group_dat <- dat[dat$group == group, ]
  wt_score <- sum(one_group_dat$cost * (one_group_dat$current_score - one_group_dat$future_score))/sum(one_group_dat$cost)
  return(wt_score)
}
```

Is there a way to vectorize the above function so that I don't have to use a loop like below? The issue is that in practice, a function is applied to tens of thousands of groups and millions of data points, so the loop is very slow.

```
# THIS IS TOO SLOW!
dat$wt_score <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(dat))
{
  dat$wt_score[i] <- wt_score(dat$group[i], dat)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to have a function:

```r
library(dplyr) # dplyr_1.1.0
dat %>%
  mutate(wt_score2 = sum(cost * (current_score - future_score))/sum(cost), .by = group)
#    group      cost current_score future_score wt_score wt_score2
# 1      1 110.95492      9.377867   0.05744175 7.745383  7.745383
# 2      2 103.20114      4.725669   0.02894589 6.618164  6.618164
# 3      3 100.61319      9.533577   0.05839552 7.247275  7.247275
# 4      4  98.45976      3.680751   0.02254551 6.894018  6.894018
# 5      5 104.48396      5.964945   0.03653676 7.095793  7.095793
# 6      1 104.05087      6.718559   0.04115283 7.745383  7.745383
# 7      2  98.18486      9.166696   0.05614828 6.618164  6.618164
# 8      3  93.50934      7.118524   0.04360272 7.247275  7.247275
# 9      4 101.75665      6.385142   0.03911057 6.894018  6.894018
# 10     5 100.79521      7.129071   0.04366732 7.095793  7.095793
# 11     1  92.10072      7.097935   0.04347660 7.745383  7.745383
# 12     2 104.64702      6.212637   0.03805394 6.618164  6.618164
# 13     3  95.33966      5.096398   0.03121670 7.247275  7.247275
# 14     4 107.13121     10.452435   0.06402375 6.894018  6.894018
# 15     5 102.71442      8.344599   0.05111273 7.095793  7.095793
```

(`wt_score` is from your `for` loop, `wt_score2` is identical).

(If you're using `dplyr` version before 1.1, then you cannot use `.by=` ... remove that, and instead use  `dat %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(...)`.)

While you tagged [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr), this can be done in base R as well.

```r
dat$wt_score3 <- ave(
  1:nrow(dat), dat$group,
  FUN = function(z) sum(dat$cost[z] * (dat$current_score[z] - dat$future_score[z]))/sum(dat$cost[z]))
dat
#    group      cost current_score future_score wt_score wt_score3
# 1      1 110.95492      9.377867   0.05744175 7.745383  7.745383
# 2      2 103.20114      4.725669   0.02894589 6.618164  6.618164
# 3      3 100.61319      9.533577   0.05839552 7.247275  7.247275
# 4      4  98.45976      3.680751   0.02254551 6.894018  6.894018
# 5      5 104.48396      5.964945   0.03653676 7.095793  7.095793
# 6      1 104.05087      6.718559   0.04115283 7.745383  7.745383
# 7      2  98.18486      9.166696   0.05614828 6.618164  6.618164
# 8      3  93.50934      7.118524   0.04360272 7.247275  7.247275
# 9      4 101.75665      6.385142   0.03911057 6.894018  6.894018
# 10     5 100.79521      7.129071   0.04366732 7.095793  7.095793
# 11     1  92.10072      7.097935   0.04347660 7.745383  7.745383
# 12     2 104.64702      6.212637   0.03805394 6.618164  6.618164
# 13     3  95.33966      5.096398   0.03121670 7.247275  7.247275
# 14     4 107.13121     10.452435   0.06402375 6.894018  6.894018
# 15     5 102.71442      8.344599   0.05111273 7.095793  7.095793
```

`stats::ave` does not take multiple arguments, so we feed it instead the row indices and handle extracting from the frame internally to the anonymous `FUN`ction.

---

Benchmarking with a small frame is premature and should not be trusted. For example, using `bench::mark` on the three on 15 rows, we see

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory              time               gc                  
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>              <list>             <list>              
1 ave         48.27µs  56.18µs    17541.        0B     8.75  8020     4      457ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [0 × 3]>  <bench_tm [8,024]> <tibble [8,024 × 3]>
2 dplyr        1.06ms   1.13ms      882.    4.85KB     5.35   330     2      374ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [16 × 3]> <bench_tm [332]>   <tibble [332 × 3]>  
3 forloop    524.06µs 621.33µs     1622.        0B     8.71   745     4      459ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [0 × 3]>  <bench_tm [749]>   <tibble [749 × 3]>
```

where `` `itr/sec` `` (higher is better) and `median` (lower is better) are two good measures. However, if we go with a much larger frame,

```r
datbig <- bind_rows(replicate(1000, dat, simplify=FALSE))
nrow(datbig)
# [1] 15000

bench::mark(...)
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                   time             gc                
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                   <list>           <list>            
1 ave        764.12µs 833.87µs   971.       1.39MB     9.85   493     5   507.87ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [42 × 3]>      <bench_tm [493]> <tibble [493 × 3]>
2 dplyr        1.34ms   1.41ms   666.    1013.19KB     4.00   333     2    500.2ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [49 × 3]>      <bench_tm [333]> <tibble [333 × 3]>
3 forloop       3.58s    3.58s     0.280   12.38GB    21.5      1    77      3.58s <NULL> <Rprofmem [375,000 × 3]> <bench_tm [1]>   <tibble [1 × 3]>
```

we can see different gains. Another (big!) factor is the number of groups, where I suspect many-more-groups will change the results. (The `for` loop is abysmally slow here ...)

---

Another alternative: iterate over the unique groups instead of each row.

```r
for (grp in unique(dat$group)) {
  dat$wt_score3[dat$group == grp] <- wt_score(grp, dat)
}
dat
#    group      cost current_score future_score wt_score wt_score3
# 1      1 110.95492      9.377867   0.05744175 7.745383  7.745383
# 2      2 103.20114      4.725669   0.02894589 6.618164  6.618164
# 3      3 100.61319      9.533577   0.05839552 7.247275  7.247275
# 4      4  98.45976      3.680751   0.02254551 6.894018  6.894018
# 5      5 104.48396      5.964945   0.03653676 7.095793  7.095793
# 6      1 104.05087      6.718559   0.04115283 7.745383  7.745383
# 7      2  98.18486      9.166696   0.05614828 6.618164  6.618164
# 8      3  93.50934      7.118524   0.04360272 7.247275  7.247275
# 9      4 101.75665      6.385142   0.03911057 6.894018  6.894018
# 10     5 100.79521      7.129071   0.04366732 7.095793  7.095793
# 11     1  92.10072      7.097935   0.04347660 7.745383  7.745383
# 12     2 104.64702      6.212637   0.03805394 6.618164  6.618164
# 13     3  95.33966      5.096398   0.03121670 7.247275  7.247275
# 14     4 107.13121     10.452435   0.06402375 6.894018  6.894018
# 15     5 102.71442      8.344599   0.05111273 7.095793  7.095793
```

Instead of iterating `nrow(dat)` times, we just iterate `length(unique(dat$group))` times. This is significantly faster than the first `for` loop. Here is the comparison (using `datbig`).

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                   time             gc                
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                   <list>           <list>            
1 ave        771.51µs 857.27µs   935.       1.39MB     9.76   479     5   512.55ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [42 × 3]>      <bench_tm [479]> <tibble [479 × 3]>
2 dplyr        1.39ms   1.51ms   617.    1013.19KB     4.00   309     2   500.44ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [49 × 3]>      <bench_tm [309]> <tibble [309 × 3]>
3 forloop       3.83s    3.83s     0.261   12.38GB    21.9      1    84      3.83s <NULL> <Rprofmem [375,000 × 3]> <bench_tm [1]>   <tibble [1 × 3]>  
4 forloop2   932.03µs 974.12µs   758.       5.04MB    22.0    379    11   500.28ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [142 × 3]>     <bench_tm [379]> <tibble [379 × 3]>
```

Showing that the reduced `for` loop is on-par with `ave` and `dplyr`.

(I can't help but see the `mem_alloc` difference as well. 12GB compared with 1-5MB? Yes, that shows another *very good reason* why doing a per-row `for` loop is not the wisest choice.)

Another alternative, if you want to squeeze some more speed out of it:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(datbig)
DT[, wt_score := sum(cost * (current_score - future_score))/sum(cost), by = .(group)]

# A tibble: 5 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                   time             gc                
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                   <list>           <list>            
1 ave        754.55µs 837.44µs  1020.       1.39MB    10.0    510     5    500.1ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [42 × 3]>      <bench_tm [510]> <tibble [510 × 3]>
2 dplyr        1.32ms   1.38ms   679.    1013.19KB     4.00   340     2   500.41ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [49 × 3]>      <bench_tm [340]> <tibble [340 × 3]>
3 forloop       4.11s    4.11s     0.243   12.38GB    22.4      1    92      4.11s <NULL> <Rprofmem [375,007 × 3]> <bench_tm [1]>   <tibble [1 × 3]>  
4 forloop2   893.94µs 958.22µs   785.       5.04MB    22.0    393    11   500.33ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [142 × 3]>     <bench_tm [393]> <tibble [393 × 3]>
5 datatable  442.91µs 481.71µs  1931.     326.06KB     4.00   966     2   500.22ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [17 × 3]>      <bench_tm [966]> <tibble [966 × 3]>
```

But I *do not recommend* switching to `data.table` spuriously: it is fast and works really well here, but it has a very different "dialect" compared to base R and dplyr. Learn to do one really well before moving on to the other. Only if your data is gargantuan (subjective and relative) would I really urge you to make this switch.

(I really do like the significantly-reduced `mem_alloc` for the DT implementation ...)

Comment: Wonderful, this is exactly what I was looking for. Is the performance relatively equal between the two approaches?

Comment: If you want to create a new dataset that just has group and the score, you could use the `summarise()` function instead of `mutate()`

Comment: For _this_ sample data (15 rows), `stats::ave` is around 20x faster than the dplyr code. The `ave` code is about 10x faster than your `for` loop. I think basing conclusions on a 15-row sample is not going to be good, though; in this case, `dplyr` is about half the speed (slower!) compared to your `for` loop. The advantage to using `dplyr` is readability and simplicity, and its gains will be more noticeable (and certainly better) with larger data.

Comment: @brinyprawn that's a great point, depending on coolhand's need for the data.

Comment: @coolhand, in case you hadn't looked, recent edits show benchmarking and an alternative base approach that is rather performant.

Comment: @r2evans thank you for the additional explanations, especially as related to the `dplyr` versions. It helped quickly troubleshoot some problems on my end